# How to retrieve image from database using python

Tags: mysql

i want to retrieve image from database using python but i have a problem where i execute this code

```
import mysql.connector
import io
from PIL import Image

connection= mysql.connector.connect(
    host ="localhost",
    user ="root",
    passwd ="pfe_altran",
    database = "testes",
    )

cursor=connection.cursor()
sql1 = "SELECT * FROM pfe WHERE id = 1 "
cursor.execute(sql1)
data2 = cursor.fetchall()

file_like2 = io.BytesIO(data2[0][0])

img1=Image.open(file_like2)
img1.show()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

and i have this error :

> file_like2 = io.BytesIO(data2[0][0]) TypeError: a bytes-like object
>   is required, not 'int'

Comment: What is the structure of the database table, from which you are retrieving the data?

Comment: **Pro tip**: Avoid `SELECT *`. Instead, name the column or columns you want. `SELECT img` might be an example. It's likely that the first column of *your* `SELECT *` result set is the `id` value, which is of course an int.

Answer (score 0):

`cursor.fetchall()` returns a list of rows to your variable so you need to handle that using a looper

```py
for row in data2:
    file_like2 = io.BytesIO(row[0]) #assumming row[0] contains the byte form of your image
```

you can use `cursor.fetchmany(size=1)` or `cursor.fetchone()` if you know that your query will return only a single row or if you know that you only need one row, this way you can manipulate it directly and not use the loop.